# How to configure UBUNTU 20.04 using the S-VIDEO and / or component video output

Tags: video

I created a USB flash drive with UBUNTU 20.04. Other versions have not been tested.
I am using the video card (XFX Geforce 8600 GT) as the S-VIDEO connector, plugged in an adapter cable for component video, where it is connected to the component video input of the LG monitor.
It is not possible to install or enter the experimentation mode, as the video is turned off before this screen.
The video signal is normally sent to the monitor, during boot up to where the keyboard below appears,
After that, UBUNTU plays the signal for the VGA output (turning off the S-VIDEO output), making it impossible to interact with the system and change to return to using S-VIDEO. Only by connecting another monitor with VGA input is it possible to access the system.
I would like to know how I can interrupt the boot sequence (probably when the keyboard is shown), change something in the system so that it continues to recognize and access S-VIDEO (and / or component video). Or by changing a file directly on the flash drive, before even using it to boot.

Comment: ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64
AND
ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64

Comment: My question has been reformulated, please reread!

Comment: You haven't made clear if you installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to the thumb-drive, or you made a persistent *live* image, or it's just a simple *live* image.  You'll be able to do anything as if it's installed on hdd/ssd if it's the first, least on the 3rd (*live* without persistence) option. Your easiest option is the *fn* keys many laptops have, eg. I can use that key to use on thinkpads to use internal, external, all (no mirror), all (mirror) etc, but clarify which option you used to put on flash drive.

Comment: I did not install ubuntu, as is clear from my previous text, as there is no visualization of the options (try or install), as the video output is lost from the video component.

I'm trying to install ubuntu on a standard desktop PC.

My PC configuration:
intel core 2 QUAD Q6600, 8GB RAM DDR800, 400 GB HD, XFX 8600GT video card, ASUS P5KSE motherboard.